# When is something considered "rude or offensive"?

Tags: discussion

I've had some recent flags on comments saying they are "rude or offensive".  I don't get to see who raises flags on comments, but I thought I would ask the community what their overall thought on these were.

The comments appeared to mostly be moderate to strong disagreement with someone else's point of view.  There were no offensive comments (racist, sexist etc) or curse/swear words.

In terms of comments directed at an individual, one comment used the phrase "don't be ridiculous" before continuing to put an opposing point of view.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind "rude or offensive" should *not* be used to flag someone engaging in comments on the question or answer for strongly expressing an alternative point of view, or critiquing the post.

Rude or offensive should be reserved for

- personal attacks.  It is for this reason that I edited out the 'don't be ridiculous' part of the comment, even though in my opinion this isn't really a personal attack.
- content would generally be construed to the general reader as offensive, for example it is racist, sexist, sectarian, or relates to sexual orientation.

Is this the correct approach, should I continue to reject flags that are merely strong opinions to the contrary?